SFMC Custom Activity - Authentication
We have a use case to call custom activity from Journey Builder to send SMS from third party application. I am not able to figure out how the authentication works when Journey Builder calls the Custom Activity events? How can we ensure the Custom Activity can only be invoked from SFMC but not from elsewhere?
If we set the useJWT: true in config.json, the request is having null in body. How to implement authentication?
{
"workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
"metaData": {
   "icon": "images/iconSmall.png",
   "category": "message"
},
"type": "REST",
"lang": {
   "en-US": {
       "name": "Twilio SMS",
       "description": "Send Twilio SMS with Journey Builder"
   }
},
"arguments": {
    "execute": {
        "inArguments": [
            {
              "to": "{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.Phone}}" ,
              "contactKey":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.ContactKey}}",
              "fname":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.FirstName}}", 
              "lname":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.LastName}}",
              "code":"{{Contact.Attribute.Customers.CountryCode}}"
            }               
        ],
        "outArguments": [],
        "url": "https://twilio-integration-3438876a2dda.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/execute",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 2000
    }
},
"configurationArguments": {
  "applicationExtensionKey": "2a7226a5-8ac3-4c54-b258-ea1fe503fd86",
   "save": {
       "url": "https://twilio-integration-34388.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/save",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 2000
   },
   "publish": {
       "url": "https://twilio-integration-34388.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/publish",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 2000
   },
   "validate": {
       "url": "https://twilio-integration-34388.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 2000
   },
   "stop": {
       "url": "https://twilio-integration-34388.herokuapp.com/journeybuilder/stop",
        "verb": "POST",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 2000
   }
},
"wizardSteps": [
   { "label": "Create SMS Message", "key": "step1" }
],
"userInterfaces": {
   "configModal": {
       "height": 600,
       "width": 800,
       "fullscreen": false
   }
},
"schema": {
    "arguments": {
        "execute": {
            "inArguments": [
                           
                {
                    "to": {
                        "dataType": "Phone",
                        "isNullable": true,
                        "direction": "out"   
                    }
                },  
                {
                    "contactKey": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isNullable": true,
                        "direction": "out"   
                    }
                },
                {
                    "fname": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isNullable": false,
                        "direction": "out"   
                    }
                },
                {
                    "body": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isNullable": false,
                        "direction": "out"   
                    }
                },                    
                {
                    "lname": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isNullable": true,
                        "direction": "out"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "code": {
                        "dataType": "String",
                        "isNullable": true,
                        "direction": "out"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "outArguments": []
        }
    }
}

